# Correct way to explicitly specialize a function template

Tags: c++, templates

I am slightly confused about the syntax of explicit template specialization for functions.

Let's say I have the following:

```
template<class T> 
void f(T t)
{}
```

I know that for an explicit specialization I need to supply `template <>` as I otherwise get overloading. The following two compile:

```
// (a)
template<> 
void f<int>(int t)
{}

//(b)
template<> 
void f(int t)
{}
```

But, what is the difference between (a) and (b)?

Comment: You can only truly specizlize class templates. For functions it's always in essence an overload.

Comment: @StoryTeller You can specialize a function template (but not partially specialize it). An overload is usually better though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As written, both do the same thing. Template argument deduction is used to figure out the type of `T` in your explicit specialization. The "fun" starts when you have overloading function templates:

```
template<class T>         //#1
void f(T t)
{}

template<class T>         //#2
void f(T* t)
{}

template<> 
void f<int*>(int* t)      // specializes #1
{}

template<> 
void f(int* t)      // specializes #2, equivalent to void f<int>(int* t)
{}
```

And the real "fun" starts when you change the order:

```
template<class T>         //#1
void f(T t)
{}

template<> 
void f(int* t)      // specializes #1, equivalent to void f<int*>(int* t)
{}

template<class T>         //#2
void f(T* t)
{}
```

In this case, you get a counterintuitive result:

```
int *p;
f(p);              // calls #2, not explicitly specialized #1
```

which is why it's usually better to use overloads rather than explicit specializations for function templates.

Comment: That is interesting, I was not aware of the concept of deduction so far. So can I say the following: it is safer to use "explicit specialization" instead of deduction?

Comment: @user2683038 For function templates, usually it's better to simply overload.